# Oracle round function with scientific notation

Tags: oracle10g, rounding, scientific-notation

Dpes anyone know how to get this to work in Oracle?  The value is what is in the table and I need to round this to 2 digits:

```
  Select round(3.00345678908765E+60, 2) from dual
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to shift the rounding by -60 decimal places (so from +2 to -58):

```sql
Select round( 3.00345678908765E+60, -58) from dual
```

Outputs:

> ```
> |                               ROUND(3.00345678908765E+60,-58) |
> | ------------------------------------------------------------: |
> | 3000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 |
> ```

If you want to round to 3 significant figures:

```sql
SELECT ROUND( value, 2 - FLOOR( LOG( 10, value ) ) ) FROM table_name;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( value ) AS
SELECT 3.00345678908765E+60 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3.00555678908765E+60 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3.05345678908765E+58 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> |                           ROUND(VALUE,2-FLOOR(LOG(10,VALUE))) |
> | ------------------------------------------------------------: |
> | 3000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 |
> | 3010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 |
> |   30500000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 |
> ```

Or you can use `TO_CHAR` to convert the value to a string rounded in scientific notation:

```sql
SELECT TO_CHAR( value, 'FM0.00EEEE' ) AS as_string,
       TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR( value, 'FM0.00EEEE' )) AS as_number
FROM   table_name;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> AS_STRING |                                                     AS_NUMBER
> :-------- | ------------------------------------------------------------:
> 3.00E+60  | 3000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
> 3.01E+60  | 3010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
> 3.05E+58  |   30500000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=27fb783bf64e05a4f97f184d0d60ba34)*

Comment: When I use the to_number(to_char(value, 'FM0.00EEEE')) I still get 3E+60

Comment: @jackstraw22 Numerically, `3E+60` and `3.00E+60` are identical values and if you round `3E+60` to 3 significant figures then you will get `3E+60` as the answer. If you want a number formatted with a specific format (i.e. `9.99E+99`, scientific notation with 3 significant figures) then you need to convert it to a string.

Comment: I'm actually just trying to return 3.  I don't want scientific notation.

Comment: @jackstraw22 But `3E+60` is not equal to `3` so you cannot "round" the value and have it magically lose 60 orders of magnitude. If you want it to be `3` then divide it by `1e60` and then round.

Comment: I see.  Thank you for the explanation.